# Java Web Start application runs under jre8u40 but not jre8u51

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have a Java web app that uses javaws. It will run fine under Java 8 update 40, but under Java 8 update 51 jp2launcher.exe just stops, without launching the application.

I have found the logs in C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log but they're identical between j8u40 and j8u51 (except of course for the order jars are loaded, the jre version and the launch time).

I have logged the launch using Process Monitor, for both jre versions. Under j8u51, jp2launcher.exe just exits with the resule "SUCCESS". Comparing the two procmon logs, I can't pick out anything unusual. They both rummage through the C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment directory and their respective C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_XX\lib directories and such like, but then the j8u51 one just exits.

The Windows event logs don't show anything Java related.

Is there anywhere else I can look for diagnostic information? Any suggestions on what might be going wrong here?

update: I have managed to run the jnlp with `set "JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-Xcheck:jni -XX:-TraceClassLoadingPreorder -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -verbose:jni -verbose:class -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\misc\logging.properties"` and log the stdout/stderr. It looks like javaws and jp2launcher log to the output, then both jre8u40 and jre8u51 versions terminate. Presumably in the j8u40 version it is launching another jp2launcher.exe to run the application.

Comparing the two output logs yields nothing of interest. The classes are loaded in nearly identical order, mostly identical classes other than a few differences that are easily explained by just being more up-to-date classes being used.

further update: I have been able to launch the application directly, using java.exe, by obtaining the client files from the server install and unpacking them. The app itself runs just fine under jre8u51, so the problem definitely lies with javaws itself.

update3: clearing the cache does not solve the problem. The issue occurs on separate machines, even with entirely fresh Java installs.

update4: As an experiment, I've just tried under Ubuntu Linux. Our product does not technically support Linux, but I thought I'd try anyway. As it happens, the behaviour is identical! Under jre8u40 the app launches, and under jre8u51 it does not!

5: it turns out the problem is happening under u45 as well, which is the update immediately after u40. So, the cause seems to be something that changed in u45, rather than in u51.

Comment: Maybe it's memory size in the jnlp file. Try toying with that.

Comment: No luck. The heap max was set to 1024mb; setting the initial heap didn't help, nor did removing all heap params and using the default, nor did setting the max down to 32mb. Setting to 8mb resulted in an out of memory error, so at least it is respecting those settings...

Comment: If you put show console on java settings and double click on the jnlp file you get no console output ?

Comment: That's correct. It terminates before the console appears. I have the console switched on in the Java settings, and I get a console under j8u40 but not under j8u51.

I'm currently trying running the jnlp with set "JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-Xcheck:jni -XX:-TraceClassLoadingPreorder -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -verbose:jni -verbose:class -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\misc\logging.properties" and redirecting stdout and stderr to read the logs. Unfortunately no exceptions in there. Going to compare with the j8u40 log; maybe the different classes loaded will give a clue.

Comment: Try clearing the cache and uninstalling the applications. `javaws -clearcache` for clearing the cache and `javaws -uninstall` for uninstallation.

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache before. This problem is happening on separate machines, with fresh installs of Java itself never mind fresh downloads of the application.

I haven't tried those specific commands, though, so here goes... ...no luck.

Comment: when you say under jre8u51 it does not launch , what do you mean , are you simply double clicking the jar? have you tried through a terminal with java - jar to get an exception or smth?

Comment: @AntJavaDev yes, double clicking it or invoking `javaws.exe` on it. As I said in my second update, if I run the app directly using `java.exe -jar` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

There are a few interacting elements here:

- The jnlp contains a j2se element for Java 6 and for Java 7. Running on Java 8, it appears that it uses the Java 6 entry.
- The Java 6 entry specifies VM arguments, while the Java 7 one does not.
- After trial and error, I have determined that the -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode VM argument is what’s causing it to fail. I don’t know what this arg does, but apparently JRE8u45+ doesn’t like it.
- I downloaded and modified the jnlp to test the above. To get javaws to actually use my changes, I had to remove the href attribute of the root jnlp element. Otherwise, javaws ignored my changes and used the copy of the jnlp on the server.

My current hypothesis is that JRE8u45+ has a bug where it uses the VM arguments from the wrong version.

I have just tested a custom jnlp with 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 entries in it, where the 1.6 one has the vm args and the 1.7 and 1.8 ones do not.

- Javaws does not prompt “The application wants to use Java 7, but you should instead use the most up-to-date one on your system, is that ok?”. Therefore, at this point is has recognised that there is a 1.8 entry in there.
- However, it fails to launch the app. Therefore, at that point, it must have got confused about what jnlp element it was on.

So, it looks like the workaround is to remove the -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode VM arg from the jnlp on the server side.